# How to avoid overlapping of opaque rectangles on graphics.drawrectangle()?

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing, mousemove

After a bunch of fail on Google searches finally I thought for asking for experts here to help me at this problem as this site always helped me.

**What I want?**

> *I want to create a Highlighter for my some kind of drawing application. I want this to be similar to the highlighter you can see on the Windows Snipping Tool.*

**What is my problem?**

> *The problem is that although I can draw the semitransparent or opaque rectangles using the code, `gfx.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Colors.GreenYellow)), x, y, width, height)`, but if I draw another rectangle overlapping any previous rectangles the colors gets darker and reduces the transparency of the rectangles where they overlapped.*

**Code:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim drag As Boolean
    Dim mouseX, mouseY As Integer
    Dim prev As Point
    Dim initi As Point
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Dim grx As Graphics = Panel1.CreateGraphics
        grx.DrawString("+", New Font("Arial", 144, FontStyle.Regular), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.GreenYellow)), New Point(200, 200))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
        drag = True
        mouseX = MousePosition.X - Me.Left - 8
        mouseY = MousePosition.Y - Me.Top - 34
        initi = New Point(mouseX, mouseY)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove
        If drag Then
            mouseX = MousePosition.X - Me.Left - 8
            mouseY = MousePosition.Y - Me.Top - 34
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
        drag = False
        prev = New Point(0, 0)
        Dim grx As Graphics = Panel1.CreateGraphics
        grx.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.GreenYellow)), initi.X, initi.Y, (mouseX - initi.X), (mouseY - initi.Y))

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Screenshot of the application (*Showing the problem*)**

- Left "+" is the one that I want to draw.
- Right "+" is the one that I get when I draw.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this link about drawing with alpha blending. There might be something that works for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/alpha-blending-lines-and-fills

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for that amazing link it was very useful. I got to know about the `ComposingMode.SourceCopy`. But the problem is it overwrites the background by picking a single color for example if I use it over an image though the drawn lines won't change their color for overlapping and keeping the drawn lines color constant but it picks only one color as the background color from the image and finally overlaps the image making it a single color or you can say erasing the image on colorful background or erasing the image using colorful erasers. :P Any more suggesstion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I've never really used graphics, but the only thing I could come up with is to create a list of the highlights to be drawn and then each time the mouse_up event fires, create a new bitmap, draw each rectangle pixel by pixel, with semi-transparent pixels to the bitmap and then draw the resulting bitmap to the panel using the panel's paint event handler that fires when you refresh the panel. This seems the built-in alpha blending that .net does automatically.

Add this to your form's variable declarations

```
Dim highlightsList As New List(Of Rectangle)
Dim bmp1 As Bitmap
```

alter your form_shown event to

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    bmp1 = New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
End Sub
```

add this sub which handles the addition of the rectangles to the list and the creation of the bitmap

```
Private Sub addRectangle(gr As Graphics, x As Integer, y As Integer, v1 As Integer, v2 As Integer)
    Dim newRectangle As New Rectangle(x, y, v1, v2)
    highlightsList.Add(newRectangle)
    Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1)
        G.Clear(Color.White)
    End Using
    bmp1.MakeTransparent(Color.White)
    For Each rect As Rectangle In highlightsList
        For i As Integer = rect.X To rect.X + rect.Width - 1
            For j As Integer = rect.Y To rect.Y + rect.Height - 1
                bmp1.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(100, Color.GreenYellow))
            Next
        Next
    Next
    Panel1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

add a handler for the panel's paint event so that when you refresh the panel, the bitmap is drawn onto it

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

and change your mouse_up event to use the above sub to do the drawing

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
    drag = False
    prev = New Point(0, 0)
    Dim grx As Graphics = Panel1.CreateGraphics
    'grx.Clear(Panel1.BackColor)
    addRectangle(grx, initi.X, initi.Y, (mouseX - initi.X), (mouseY - initi.Y))
End Sub
```

This seems to work, but if you're using the panel for anything other that showing highlights, it may not work as expected.

Comment: Your approach seems good I have planned something like that but was not getting the code `bmp1.MakeTransparent(Color.White)` but the problem is I won't be using rectangles actually instead I am going to using **`FillEllipse`**. Here I used rectangle to show a clean visualization. But anyhow I will try to implement your idea with mine to check if I can sort this problem out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works: There are no borders you can't even distinguish the different boxes:
I changed the following:

```
New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.GreenYellow)), New Point(200, 200))
```

Into this:

```
New SolidBrush(Color.GreenYellow), New Point(200, 200))
```

For BOTH times: For the declarations and for the `Panel1_MouseDown`
That is because this sets the Alpha to 1 by defualt making unchangable as well, so over lapping will not change any colours, layers, or visibility.

You should only use `FromArgb` when you are going to control the alpha of the colour, but in this case you are letting the computer do that for you

Comment: Maybe you got my question wrong because using your code will not give the error 'changing color on overlapping' but that is because it will draw a solid lines but not a semitransparent** line which in my case I need. Because I want it to act as a highlighter as I mentioned in the question. And please correct me if I misunderstand your answer and concept.

Comment: I think there is a bit of misunderstanding. Your question never said you want an error trigger of any type, and I have tested my code to give what you asked for in the picture. Read my answer again please.

Comment: What I meant is your code `New SolidBrush(Color.GreenYellow), New Point(200, 200))` would never give a semitransparent drawing according to my knowledge (correct me if I am wrong). But in my question I asked for semitransparent drawings.